# JSON:API specification filter parameters with Flurl HTTP

Tags: c#, json-api, flurl

We use JSON:API specification on our API. Currently having issues with formatting the filter params to the specification using Flurl in C#.

Example:

```
        var url = await Helpers.GetAPIPath()
           .AppendPathSegment("orders")
           .WithOAuthBearerToken(Helpers.GetAPIToken())
           .SetQueryParams(new {
               filters = "[work_orders]=true,[status]=pending_approval",
               include = "shipping-address,inventory-items.part"
           }).GetAsync();
```

This produces `/orders?filters[work_orders]=true,[status]=pending_approval&include=shipping-address,inventory-items.part`

Here's documentation on a JSON:API request with multiple filters https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering

How can I structure the filters similar to `filter[work_orders]=true,filter[status]=pending_approval` for the JSON:API specification?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The correct link would be `?filter[work_orders]=true&filter[status]=pending_approval`. Using a `&` to separate query params and not `,`.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet was able to achieve the correct filtering parameters. Not sure if there's a cleaner way to implement this but so far it's working!

```
         var orderResponse = await Helpers.GetAPIPath()
            .AppendPathSegment("orders")
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(Helpers.GetAPIToken())
            .SetQueryParam("filter[work_orders]=true")
            .SetQueryParam("filter[status]=pending_approval")
            .SetQueryParams(new {
                include = "shipping-address,inventory-items.part",
            }).GetAsync();
```

Comment: Yep, this works. The problem with the object syntax is the `[` and `]` characters aren't legal in a C# property name. Flurl will accept a dictionary object (with string keys) here, or the way you've done it here works too, but you'd typically separate name and value, i.e. `SetQueryParam("filter[work_orders]", "true")`.